# sikuli observing multiple images with priority

Tags: python, sikuli

I've defined a sikuli module which is used to click on an image when something appears inside a region.

```
# observer.py

from sikuli import *

class Observer:

    # When "observedImage" appears inside "region", double click on "reactImage"
    def __init__(self, region, observedImage, reactImage):
        self.region = region
        self.observedImage = observedImage
        self.reactImage = reactImage

    def start(self):
        self.region.onAppear(self.observedImage, self.appearHandler)
        self.region.observe(FOREVER, background = True)

    def appearHandler(self, event):
        doubleClick(self.reactImage)
        event.repeat()

    def stop(self):
        self.region.stopObserver()
```

Here's how to use it:

```
import observer
import time

observer.Observer(Region(111,222,333,444), "imageToBeDetected1.png", "imageToBeClicked1.png").start()
observer.Observer(Region(555,666,66,666), "imageToBeDetected2.png", "imageToBeClicked2.png").start()

while True:
  print('waiting')
  time.sleep(1)
```

The problem with the above code is that when `imageToBeDetected1` and `imageToBeDetected2` both appear in `Region(111,222,333,444)` and `Region(555,666,66,666)` respectively, my mouse will move between `imageToBeClicked1` and `imageToBeClicked2`. I want only `imageToBeDetected1` to be clicked in this situation.

`imageToBeDetected2` should be ignored when `imageToBeDetected1` and `imageToBeDetected2` both appear in `Region(111,222,333,444)` and `Region(555,666,66,666)`, respectively.

How can I modify my code so that `imageToBeDetected1` has a higher priority over `imageToBeDetected2`?

Or is there a better way to observe multiple images with sikuli?